# Jar File not executing from PHP

Tags: php, windows, jar, cmd, xampp

I am trying to execute a Jar file from PHP on XAMPP windows server 2012.

A simple "Hello World" jar file execution works

```
$output = exec("java -jar C:\User\HelloWorld.jar");

echo $output;
```

However, a Jar file that opens the window of another program (a Browser, Paint, Notepad, etc..), does not execute from PHP although I tested it manually in the command window and it worked. I also tried to execute the jar using a batch file (which also works on clicking) but fails to execute from PHP.

I gave full permissions to the Apache server to act as a logged in user, and still it is not working.

I have been researching for 2 days and trying different combinations of solutions on forums (system, shell_exec, exec,..), but nothing worked for me.

Appreciate anyone's help please, before my VPS subscription ends

Comment: Is there any error in your xampp log files?

Comment: I used pclose(popen("start notepad.exe", "r"))am able to see the processes in  the task manager, however the program GUI is not opening.